# How to get ACL of a content in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to get ACLs attached to a document in alfresco repository. I believe ACL are stored in solr index along with content.

I did some research and found out that CMIS provides ACLService as below.

```
AclService aclService = session.getBinding().getAclService();
```

But on alfresco repository side of things, there is no such equivalent.

Has anybody any idea on how to get ACL for a document.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions are stored in the DB but also indexed into SOLR to filter search results by permissions without DB access.
I guess you're looking for bean `PermissionService` interface `org.alfresco.service.cmr.security.PermissionService`:

Get all the AccessPermissions that are set for anyone for the given node:

```
public Set<AccessPermission> getAllSetPermissions(NodeRef nodeRef);
```

Get all the AccessPermissions that are granted/denied to the current authentication for the given node:

```
public Set<AccessPermission> getPermissions(NodeRef nodeRef);
```

Comment: Also to compare authorities of a user to ACL for content, use authorityService.getAuthoritiesForUser(userName) method.